# How do you disable swipe to open drawer navigator, but keep swipe to navigate back?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, swipe

I'm in this situation where I have a screen in a drawer navigator that I want to be able to swipe right to navigate back to the previous screen. But since it's in a drawer navigator, my right swipe opens the drawer and I am unable to navigate back without pressing the back arrow. Is there a way to disable to drawer swipe for that screen, but keep the swipe to navigate. Any help is appreciated. TYIA

Answer (score 2):

You need disable swipe to open/close drawer with `swipeEnabled` prop in `screenOptions`, like:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    // ... defined something
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }}>
  // ... your drawer
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

And you need define a drawer item in 1 stack be like my example: https://snack.expo.dev/@pqv2210/q-74710170

Answer (score 0):

```
// Solution 1 
**React Navigation 6**

In screen options: Set edge width to 0.

<Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            swipeEdgeWidth: 0,
        }}
    >
        {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>


**React Navigation 5**

In your createDrawerNavigator config:

const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  }
}, 
{
  edgeWidth: 0
})

//Solution 2 : This may also work.

You can use the drawerLockMode in the screen navigation options using the option locked-open

locked-open: the drawer will stay opened and not respond to gestures. The drawer may still be opened and closed programmatically

Other options can be viewed here

static navigationOptions = {
     drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).